# PhpUnit, сборщик отчета CodeCoverage. Как такое происходит?

Tags: юнит-тесты, php, phpunit, codecoverage

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое вообще может получиться, что в методе, в середине кода может быть вызвана одна строчка пятью тестами, а первые две - только двумя, а промежуточные вообще помечены как не тестированные?

Я в замешательстве...

*Картинки кликабельны*
[image]

[image]

Generated by `PHP_CodeCoverage 1.2.12` using `PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3` and `PHPUnit 3.7.22`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Некропостер в треде!

Предположу, что в выражении `$var = someVlue;` коверить требуется правую и левую части. `new A_Model_contact()` отковерилось в куче других методов; `$contact` коверить явно не надо, поэтом строчка помечается как точно работающая и покрытая соседними тестами. Аналогично с проставляемыми полями: где-то они уже были проставлены, и поэтому считаются покрытыми. Единственное, что мне непонятно, так это почему потенциально опасный референс элемента массива считается за безопасное присвоение.
Запускать codecoverage и проверять мне сейчас лень |:

Comment: Как показал сбор статистики по коду, проблема где-то в методе isset, так как в коде именно на нем начинается красота, после установки нового пхпюнит и сборщика, проблема ушла